# Concat string from specific column and new string value SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have table called `events` and I can't update it where the column contains data info and I am trying to append the string the to the specific column
this is query I tried.

`Volunteer` is column in `Events` table and break the line

```
 UPDATE Events 
 SET Volunteers = Volunteers + @Volunteers +'\n'  
 WHERE Event_Name = @Event_Name

 UPDATE Events 
 SET Volunteers += @Volunteers +'\n'  
 WHERE Event_Name = @Event_Name
```

Tried both ways but neither of them works.

For example column contains "abc" and add another from parameter "123"

so it would look like this

```
 abc
 123
```

in database suppose to look like this

I am using Visual Studio (Windows Form Application), with a SQL Server CE database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So in a single row of a table you need store two lines!!

Comment: i want to append the string value for specific column in this case is Volunteers so when this query run it should append new string to existing string value.

Comment: How did you check the field? Are you using the Sql Server Management Studio interface or are you reloading the data and looking at it using the debugger?

Comment: I am Visual Studio and a Windows Form Application. I am using a dataset from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Try Using CHAR(13)

        see I explain 

        Declare @TableField varchar(50)
        Declare @Volunteers varchar(50)
        Declare @Result varchar(50)

        SET @TableField = 'abc'
        SET @Volunteers = '123'

        SET @Result= @TableField+CHAR(13)+@Volunteers

        SELECT @Result AS Result

        OUTPUT Paste Then like 

        abc
        123

        either char(13) or char(10) would work. 

        but ,char(10) = \n - new line
             char(13) = \r - go to the beginning of the line

        You Set On  Query AS 

         UPDATE Events 
         SET Volunteers = Volunteers+CHAR(13)+@Volunteers
         WHERE Event_Name = @Event_Name
```